# Pymongo Pydantic timestamp schema

Tags: python, pymongo, pydantic

Im trying to insert a document with a timestamp.
However, no matter what i try i get the following error:

> pymongo.errors.WriteError: 'timestamp' must be present and contain a
> valid BSON UTC datetime value, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 2,
> 'errmsg': "'timestamp' must be present and contain a valid BSON UTC
> datetime value"}

Model:

```
class Meta(BaseModel):
   namespace: str
   key: str
   owner: str

class Telemetry(BaseModel):
    name: str
    timestamp: datetime
    value: float
    meta: Union[Meta, None] = None
```

Document object:

```
telemetry = {
    'timestamp':'2022-11-02T00:00:00.000+00:00',
    'value':100,
    'meta': {
        'namespace':'name',
        'key':'key',
        'owner':'owner'
    }
}
```

Any pointers?